# Is there a way to detect elasticsearch has exited and restart it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I use the command

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

to start the elasticsearch server in ubuntu. Somtimes i see that the service has exited. This maybe because of the memory limit hit. I then have to reexecute the command

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

The cons of this approach is that my application crashes when elasticsearch server is down so i really need to automatically detect when elasticsearch stops and then restart it. Is there a way to do this? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to tune your elasticsearch cluster so it does not exit unexpectedly

Comment: can you elaborate a little more on this one?

Comment: do you mean to reduce memory so that it doesnt hit the system memory limit?

Comment: sudo service elasticsearch status